# VLC internet multicast

Tags: vlc-media-player, streaming, multicast

I want to stream video using `VLC` so everyone can connect to my pc and watch it. Is there any way to do it? As I understand I can multicast video only in my network (but I need it to be available from the internet). I tried to stream video specifying just port. In this case I could connect from internal network but not from the outside.

**EDIT**

If I try to stream via `http` I can't connect from outside my network. I've forwarded ports in my router. My streaming options for example

```
:sout=#transcode{vcodec=theo,vb=800,scale=1,acodec=vorb,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:http{mux=ogg,dst=:12100/} :sout-keep
```

Comment: multicast doesn't really work across the Internet.  Routers must be configured to support it, and most are not configured.

Comment: Are there any other options how to make my video avaliable to several people in the internet using vlc?

Comment: Don't multicast.  Use the http stream options.

Comment: But in this case I can't connect from outside. Maybe I'm doing something wrong. I've edited my post. Please look.

Comment: Have you configured your router to permit it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a tutorial at [zdwired](http://www.zdwired.com/stream-over-internet-using-vlc/), which shows how to stream through `http` to the internet:

> 1. First of all run your VLC media player and press Ctrl+S on your keyboard, a pop up window will open like the image below. Just add any
>      of your audio or video file from your PC and click Stream.
>
>    [image]
> 2. In the next window click next. There’s in the destination setup select new destination as HTTP and add it. Remember the port for new
>      destination, default port is 8080 but you can enter your own random
>      port number. Set transcoding option as Video + MP3 and click next.
>
>    [image]
> 3. In Option setup check box against Stream all elementary streams and click Stream button and here's you completed the setup of stream on
>      the source, in the next steps you'll set to play that stream on
>      destination.
>
>    [image]
> 4. Now it's time to enjoy your stream on destination machine but you can test it on your PC with two VLC media player running, one as a
>      source of stream and other as the destination, where you'll watch
>      stream. Before going on the next step check your IP address. Hit
>      Windows key enter CMD in search and press Enter, now enter ipconfig in
>      command prompt and hit Enter. There’s you'll see the IP address of
>      your PC.
>
>    [image]
> 5. Now open new VLC media player if you test it on the same PC and press Ctrl+N. In the network URL field enter your IP address and port
>      as http:// youripaddress : port. Default port is 8080 but if you set your
>      own at the streaming source setup then enter that here and click Play
>      button and there’s your stream starts playing in VLC media player.
>
>    [image]
>
>    [image]
>
>    You can see in the image movie is streaming. There’s one VLC player stream the movie and other play that
>      stream on IP address of stream source. You can share your media
>      content with your friends live without uploading to internet, just by
>      giving IP address and port to your friends. So enjoy your streaming.

[Source](http://www.zdwired.com/stream-over-internet-using-vlc/)